# Ordem alfabética Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, controller

Preciso colocar minha categoria em ordem alfabética:

```
@posts_categories = Admin::PostCategory.all
```

Comment: a ordenação deve ser feita com base em qual campo?

Comment: categorias tenho que colocar minha categoria em ordem alfabética

Comment: mas esta categoria possui um campo que vai servir de critério para ordenar. qual é este campo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ordenação pode ser feita desta forma:

```
@posts_categories = Admin::PostCategory.order(name: :asc)
```

Isso se a tabela poss_categories possui o campo "name". Caso não, basta substituir pelo nome do campo a usar como critério de ordenação.

O `asc` diz que a ordenação será feita de forma ascendente (A-Z ou 0 - 10...)

Para saber mais sobre o assunto, visite: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: Obrigada... deu certo

Comment: @MichellySabatiny não te esqueças de dar uma olhada no link que deixei aí

Comment: Pode deixar...! Estou indo ver agora